# In Visual Studio, how can I debug a Web API request without pausing background threads?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Perhaps I'm not correctly understanding how debugging works in VS, on a high level, but I assumed the following: if I hit a breakpoint on either a UI thread or a web request action method, and remain paused there for a while, that any background threads in the process would continue to run. Is that not correct? Because what I'm seeing is my background network logic timing out whenever I break for ~30 seconds on a web request, causing exceptions to occur.

Either way, I need to be able to debug my web requests without affecting background stuff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use certain tool like the Fiddler to check that whether the server side has receives the request and send the response to the client during the breakpoint was hit. For example, if it sends the request, but no response from the server side with a breakpoint, it would impact the result. Of course, it is also related to the time out limitation in your client side.

If the debugger breakpoint really impacts the web request, one idea is that you could debug it using other method like using debug class to output text: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/815788.